# Edit the title page of a beamer presentation

Tags: beamer

How can I edit titlepage of beamer presentation.

[image]

The code that I'm using

```
\documentclass[serif,9pt]{beamer}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
  \usetheme{Warsaw} %Themes 
  \definecolor{colorA}{RGB}{96, 34, 59}
   \definecolor{colorB}{RGB}{140, 151, 154}
   \setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=colorA,bg=colorB}

     \usepackage[ruled, linesnumbered, vlined]{algorithm2e}
     \usepackage{epsfig, subfigure, amssymb, multirow, algorithmic, amsmath}
  \newcommand*{\superscript}[1]{\ensuremath{^{\rm #1}}}
  \newcommand*{\subscript}[1]{\ensuremath{_{\rm #1}}}

 \title[{\sc Optimisation d'un syst\`eme de distribution alimentaire } \hspace{0.8cm} 
   \insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber]{{\sc OPTIMISATION D'UN SYST\`EME DE DISTRIBUTION ALIMENTAIRE }}
 %\institute{Groupe de recherche Mathématiques et Sciences des Données \\ Département MATHS et 
 INFORMATIQUE \\ LIPIM-ENSAk}

\author[Author_name --- {\sc Juillet 20, 2020}]{{Author_name}}
\noindent% just to prevent indentation narrowing the line width for this line
 \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{logo-ensak.png}%
 \begin{minipage}[b]{0.7\textwidth}
 \centering
Université Sultan Moulay Slimane\\
 \'Ecole Nationale des Sciences Appliquées \\
  Khouribga
 \end{minipage}%
 \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{slides/uni.png}

   \begin{document}

    \titlepage

       \begin{frame}
    \end{frame}
     \end{document}
```

I need your help .

Thank you

Comment: Please don't shout so, remove the capitals from your title.

Comment: code does not compile -- no end document-- too many mistakes-- how did you get the output shown in the image

Comment: it does compile

Comment: @HBoulmi it does not, it creates multiple errors and some which are beyond what one guess you meant. To verify, please copy your code in a new `*.tex` document and try for yourself.

Comment: Please never ever ignore error messages! Even if you get something that on first glance resembles a pdf file, there can still be issues with it. After an error, TeX only tries to recover enough to syntax check more of the file, it does not try to make sensible output after an error.

Comment: Thank you for your reply , I'm new in latex , I'm still learning about it

Answer (score 2):

The following could serve as a point to start from:

[image]

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{demo}{graphicx} % do not use in your actual document!
\documentclass[serif,9pt]{beamer}


\makeatletter
\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{my title page}[1][]
{
  \vbox{}
  \vfill
  \begingroup
    \centering
    {\usebeamercolor[fg]{titlegraphic}\inserttitlegraphic\par}
    \vskip0.5em
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,#1]{title}
      \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle\par%
      \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty%
      \else%
        \vskip0.25em%
        {\usebeamerfont{subtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subtitle}\insertsubtitle\par}%
      \fi%     
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \vskip1em\par
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,#1]{author}
      \usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,#1]{institute}
      \usebeamerfont{institute}\insertinstitute
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,#1]{date}
      \usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate
    \end{beamercolorbox}
  \endgroup
  \vfill
}

\defbeamertemplate*{footline}{my split theme}
{%
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm plus1fill,rightskip=.3cm]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor ~\textemdash~ \insertdate
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle\nobreak\hfill\usebeamercolor[fg]{page number in head/foot}\usebeamerfont{page number in head/foot}\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother

\usetheme{Warsaw} %Themes 
\definecolor{colorA}{RGB}{96, 34, 59}
\definecolor{colorB}{RGB}{140, 151, 154}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=colorA,bg=colorB}
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{title page}[my title page][rounded=true,shadow=\beamer@themerounded@shadow]
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[my split theme]
\makeatother


   
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[ruled, linesnumbered, vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{epsfig, subfigure, amssymb, multirow, algorithmic, amsmath}
\newcommand*{\superscript}[1]{\ensuremath{^{\rm #1}}}
\newcommand*{\subscript}[1]{\ensuremath{_{\rm #1}}}

\title{\scshape Optimisation d'un syst\`eme de distribution alimentaire}
\institute{Groupe de recherche Mathématiques et Sciences des Données \\
           Département MATHS et  INFORMATIQUE \\ 
           LIPIM-ENSAk}
\titlegraphic{%
   \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth, valign=c]{logo-ensak.png}% 
   \quad\quad 
   \begin{minipage}{0.55\textwidth}
     \centering 
       Université Sultan Moulay Slimane\\
       \'Ecole Nationale des Sciences Appliquées \\
       Khouribga 
   \end{minipage}%
   \quad\quad %
   \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth, valign=c]{slides/uni.png}%
   }
\author{Author: name}
\date{Juillet 20, 2020}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \maketitle
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```